# GC OutOfMemory error when deleting a large amount of nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a large amount of highly connected nodes that I sometimes want removed from the database.  Through a couple traversals, I wind up with a list of nodes I want to delete:

```
for (Node nodeToDelete : nodesToDelete)
{
    for (Relationship rel : nodeToDelete.getRelationships())
    {
        rel.delete();
    }

    nodeToDelete.delete();
}
```

The problem is that no matter how large I set my Heap, I keep getting: 
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**

What is the best way to delete a large list of nodes?  I know I have to remove their relationships first before actually deleting them - I step through the code and it appears to fail on a relationship delete.  Is there a better function for deleting nodes than what I have?  Everything is wrapped in a transaction which is very important since no part of this delete is allowed to fail - could that be an issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it as a batch. The problem is that your deletes are wrapped in a transaction, which can be reverted, but in order to store that reversion, it is stored in memory. try doing this.

```
long counter = 0;
for (Node nodeToDelete : nodesToDelete)
{
    if (counter == 1000) {
        tx.success();
        tx.finish();
        tx = db.beginTransaction();
        counter = 0;
    }
    for (Relationship rel : nodeToDelete.getRelationships())
    {
        rel.delete();
    }

    nodeToDelete.delete();
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: don't you need the tx.success();tx.finish() section at the end of the root for loop, too?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming he would inject this code over what part he provided above, IE he'd keep the `finish()` he already had.

Comment: How to do this batching using Cypher? I have a 9 GB database that has several million nodes, I'd like to delete a major part of it (but not all). Yet a single `MATCH ({x: 'something'}) DETACH DELETE x` throws `OutOfMemoryError` even with a <del>`-Xmx4g`</del> `-Xmx10g` !! (total RAM is 16 GB)

Comment: Even this: `MATCH (n:owl_Thing {_partition: 'lumen_yago'}) RETURN count(n) AS cnt` takes 41 seconds :( Using `-Xmx10g`. Returned an int of about 21,000,000. (so contains 21 million nodes)